# Google Maps autocomplete field doesn't list adresses

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-api

I have created a project on Google api Console and got a Browser Key in order to display a textbox with Google Map autocomplete. Although I am not getting any error in the browser console, the autocomplete doesn't work. Here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload = "initialize();">
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "text" id = "autocomplete" placeholder = "Η Διευθυνσή σας"/>
</form>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBmm_XsU6QttZNhw1RfxRHTpavpbN33jX0&libraries=places,geometry" async defer></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
        var autocomplete;
        function initialize() {
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
              { types: ['geocode'] });

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

and here is my test page: http://www.lefko-cafe.gr/content/addrress_finder.php

The weird thing is that the exactly same  html is working in another domain (except the key): http://www.laoskaikalamaki.gr/content/addrress_finder.php

Answer (score 3):

With the changes to [Maps API Standard Plan](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) if you want to use the `Places Service` you need to enable `Google Places API Web Service` [in the developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

The same goes for any other Service, if you want to us `Directions` you need to enable `Google Maps Directions API`, if you want to use `Geocoding` you need to enable `Google Maps Geocoding API`.

This changed recently, so no need to be sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your examples works for me.  The onload event and the completion of the script load are two different asynchronous events, they may fire in different orders on different server/browser locations.  I get a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`
You have `async defer` in your include of the API but no `&callback=initialize` parameter.

**code snippet:**

```
<body> <!-- remove onload = "initialize();" -->
<form method = "post">
    <input type = "text" id = "autocomplete" placeholder = "Η Διευθυνσή σας"/>
</form>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBmm_XsU6QttZNhw1RfxRHTpavpbN33jX0&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Η Διευθυνσή σας" />
</form>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var autocomplete;

  function initialize() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
      (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: So what am I doing wrong? I think it's something regarding the api key but I can't figure it out

Comment: Is your key enabled for the places API and the problematic URL?

Comment: Oh... That was the problem! Really sorry for this. Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

api-key is needed if your domain is after june 22,2016. You need to enable following api if you want to use google autocomplete only with javascript

- Google Maps JavaScript API
- Google Places API Web Service